# C# / Windows Forms - How can I determine if someone is currently "Dragging"? (not in DragOver event)

Tags: c#, winforms

Assuming that I'm in a function that is called in a Timer on in Windows Forms class... how can I tell if the user is currently attempting to "Drag" something?

example:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // This doesn't exist of course :)
    if (Mouse.IsDragging) ...
}
```

EDIT: I should specify that I know that I can override DragEnter and DragLeave to set my own private variable... but I'm asking/looking for a '.Nety' solution if one exists.

Comment: Could you handle DragOver/DragEnter/DragLeave events to set a private field to true/false?

Comment: I *could*, but I don't really want to have to do that if at all possible.

Comment: Are you trying to detect dragging anywhere (in other apps as well), or dragging in your app only?

Comment: In my app alone would be good enough, but globally would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy:

```
        bool mDragging;
...
            mDragging = true;
            DoDragDrop("test", DragDropEffects.All);
            mDragging = false;
```

Universal:

```
    public static bool IsDragging()
    {
        StackFrame[] frames = new StackTrace(false).GetFrames();
        foreach (StackFrame frame in frames)
        {
            System.Reflection.MethodBase mb = frame.GetMethod();
            if (mb.Module.Name == "System.Windows.Forms.dll" && mb.Name == "DoDragDrop")
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Crazy - but good enough :) ... I wish I was able to use WPF on this project!